# MySQL/Maria Database not loading: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: debian, mysql, mariadb

**Setup**

- Server computer

  - Distro: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8
  - Kernel: 4.9.35-v7+ armv7l (32 bit)

My MySQL database is not loading

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-01-11 01:09:32 UTC; 6h ago
  Process: 914 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 11 01:08:48 Xroklaus systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
Jan 11 01:09:32 Xroklaus mysql[914]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Jan 11 01:09:32 Xroklaus systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 11 01:09:32 Xroklaus systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Jan 11 01:09:32 Xroklaus systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

Error log

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ sudo cat /var/lib/mysql/Xroklaus.err
180111  1:04:39 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
180111  1:04:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
180111  1:04:39 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'host'
180111 01:04:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/Xroklaus.pid ended
180111 01:08:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
180111  1:08:53 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.32-MariaDB-0+deb8u1) starting as process 1347 ...
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1616887 and 1616887 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1616913 in the ib_logfiles!
180111  1:08:54 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
180111  1:08:55 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
180111  1:08:55 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
180111  1:08:55 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.1 started; log sequence number 1616913
180111  1:08:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
180111  1:08:55 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
180111  1:08:55 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
180111  1:08:55 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'host'
180111 01:08:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/Xroklaus.pid ended
```

Looks like it's missing a file.

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ sudo mysql_upgrade
Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

[update]

I'm able to run the daeman with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`,
but the upgrade fails:

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ sudo mysql_upgrade
Phase 1/6: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Processing databases
mysql
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
mysql.columns_priv
Error    : Incorrect file format 'columns_priv'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.db
Error    : Incorrect file format 'db'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.event
Error    : Incorrect file format 'event'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.func
Error    : Incorrect file format 'func'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.gtid_slave_pos                               OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.index_stats                                  OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
mysql.plugin
Error    : Incorrect file format 'plugin'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv
Error    : Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.roles_mapping                                OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.table_stats                                  OK
mysql.tables_priv
Error    : Incorrect file format 'tables_priv'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user
Error    : Incorrect file format 'user'
error    : Corrupt

Repairing tables
mysql.columns_priv
Error    : Incorrect file format 'columns_priv'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.db
Error    : Incorrect file format 'db'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.event
Error    : Incorrect file format 'event'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.func
Error    : Incorrect file format 'func'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.plugin
Error    : Incorrect file format 'plugin'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.procs_priv
Error    : Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.tables_priv
Error    : Incorrect file format 'tables_priv'
error    : Corrupt
mysql.user
Error    : Incorrect file format 'user'
error    : Corrupt
Phase 2/6: Fixing views
Phase 3/6: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 141: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 143: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 144: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 146: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 147: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 148: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 150: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 155: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 156: Incorrect file format 'tables_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 158: Incorrect file format 'tables_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 166: Incorrect file format 'tables_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 174: Incorrect file format 'columns_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 177: Incorrect file format 'columns_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 186: Incorrect file format 'columns_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 189: Incorrect file format 'func'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 191: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 192: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 200: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 201: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 205: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 211: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 212: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 214: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 215: Incorrect file format 'func'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 216: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 220: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 244: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 249: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 279: Incorrect file format 'func'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 281: Incorrect file format 'func'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 312: Incorrect file format 'plugin'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 317: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 318: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 319: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 322: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 323: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 324: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 325: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 328: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 329: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 330: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 332: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 333: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 334: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 337: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 338: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 339: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 340: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 343: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 344: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 345: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 346: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 349: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 350: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 352: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 353: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 355: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 356: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 357: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 358: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 361: Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 364: Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 367: Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 370: Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 373: Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 472: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 473: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 474: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 475: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 476: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 477: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 478: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 479: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 480: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 481: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 515: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 516: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 517: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 518: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 519: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 521: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 524: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 526: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 529: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 531: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 534: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 536: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 538: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 539: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 541: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 542: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 543: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 546: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 547: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 548: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 550: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 551: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 552: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 553: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 554: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 555: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 556: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 557: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 558: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 559: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 1436 (HY000) at line 574: Thread stack overrun:  4864 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 0 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 577: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 597: Incorrect file format 'user'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 598: Incorrect file format 'db'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 599: Incorrect file format 'tables_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 600: Incorrect file format 'columns_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 601: Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 603: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 608: Incorrect file format 'procs_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 609: Incorrect file format 'tables_priv'
ERROR 130 (HY000) at line 625: Incorrect file format 'event'
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 644: Table 'cond_instances' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 669: Table 'events_waits_current' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 694: Table 'events_waits_history' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 719: Table 'events_waits_history_long' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 732: Table 'events_waits_summary_by_instance' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 745: Table 'events_waits_summary_by_host_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 758: Table 'events_waits_summary_by_user_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 772: Table 'events_waits_summary_by_account_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 785: Table 'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 797: Table 'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 806: Table 'file_instances' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 835: Table 'file_summary_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 866: Table 'file_summary_by_instance' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 879: Table 'socket_instances' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 909: Table 'socket_summary_by_instance' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 938: Table 'socket_summary_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 973: Table 'host_cache' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 982: Table 'mutex_instances' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 996: Table 'objects_summary_global_by_type' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1006: Table 'performance_timers' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1016: Table 'rwlock_instances' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1025: Table 'setup_actors' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1033: Table 'setup_consumers' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1042: Table 'setup_instruments' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1053: Table 'setup_objects' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1061: Table 'setup_timers' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1106: Table 'table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1150: Table 'table_io_waits_summary_by_table' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1229: Table 'table_lock_waits_summary_by_table' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1249: Table 'threads' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1265: Table 'events_stages_current' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1281: Table 'events_stages_history' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1297: Table 'events_stages_history_long' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1310: Table 'events_stages_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1323: Table 'events_stages_summary_by_host_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1336: Table 'events_stages_summary_by_user_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1350: Table 'events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1362: Table 'events_stages_summary_global_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1408: Table 'events_statements_current' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1454: Table 'events_statements_history' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1500: Table 'events_statements_history_long' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1532: Table 'events_statements_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1564: Table 'events_statements_summary_by_host_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1596: Table 'events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1629: Table 'events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1660: Table 'events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1669: Table 'hosts' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1678: Table 'users' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1688: Table 'accounts' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1723: Table 'events_statements_summary_by_digest' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1733: Table 'session_connect_attrs' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1739: Table 'session_account_connect_attrs' already exists
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

[update]

Fixed by dropping all tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MySQL DB is corrupted.

Backup your /var/lib/mysql first.

Then do:

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

or for Debian

```
 mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

While running it, do:

```
$ mysql
mysql> use mysql
mysql> repair table host use_frm;
mysql> exit
```

Stop `mysqld`now and restart the service:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

That should fix it for now. Be aware you are prone to these little problems running a MySQL DB from an SD card. The raspberry is also known for having sporadic SD corruption problems when turning it off.

Using intensive database operations in an SD card with also shorten it´s useful life faster.

Consider moving the OS or at least the MySQL DB to an external disk or an USB pen.

If you have upgraded MySQL versions recently, and/or still got MySQL errors, run now the upgrade operation:

```
sudo mysql_upgrade
```

This operation fixes tables and internal data representation that change between different MySQL versions.

PS. It is possible that more tables are corrupted and the DB integrity is compromised for good. Consider restoring a recent MySQL DB backup dump or creating it over from scratch if the data is not important.

Comment: Great answer, but for some reason I'm still not able to rerun/repair it.

Comment: I managed to get to the second part by entering mysqld_safe instead of mysqld. mysql_upgrade does not have a "-A" option.

Comment: And I don't mind if I have to destroy the DB. The data is not that important. The application using it just needs to run.

Comment: Thanks @Folatt update the answer with your inputs and updated the answer with SD card considerations about using a DB on it.